# How to Store and Retrieve Image in SQL Server Using Laravel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-4

How to store and retrieve an image using laravel? I have an image field of "image" datatype in sql server. I would like to save image and retrieve it using laravel? Find below the code I have used.

```
$img_path = Input::file('file') -> getRealPath();
$image_data = file_get_contents($img_path);
$base64 = base64_encode($image_data);
$logoTypes = new logoTypes;
$logoTypes -> Type = "Image";
$logoTypes -> image = $base64;
$logoTypes -> created_by =  Auth::user()->id;
$logoTypes -> updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
$logoTypes -> save();
```

But, i'm getting the following error,

```
{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) is incompatible with image (SQL: insert into [logoTypes] ([Type], [image], [created_by], [updated_by], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (Image, \/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wCEAAkGBxQSEhUUEhISFBQUFhQUFBQVFRQUFRQUFxQXFhQUFxQYHCggGBolHBQUITIhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGxAQGywkICQsLCwvLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLPMnEDzVTr3qpqgbmkfiA5qp2ILNOvOqqdeocA3NMcRXDiSyjsQ6ql2I9UNkV3Nc7FFwYwFjH4l1Q78S6qu6J3DcPxwDihax...., 1, 1, 2014-06-23 17:20:18.000, 2014-06-23 17:20:18.000))","file":"D:\\wamp\\www\\Lhrms\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php","line":555}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Laravel Staper: https://github.com/CodeSleeve/laravel-stapler

Laravel-Stapler is a Stapler-based file upload package for the Laravel framework. It can be used to add file file uploads (as attachment objects) to your ORM records.